# Using matlabpool with a specified number of workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, hyperthreading, matlabpool

I've been using the command `matlabpool open 8` for a while in order to speed up things.
However I just tried using it and am denied 8 cores and now limited to 4.

My laptop is an i7 with 4 cores but hyperthreaded which meant I had no issue making matlab working on 8 virtual cores.

Simultaneously I noticed the following warning message:

`Warning: matlabpool will be removed in a future release.
Use parpool instead.`

Seems like MathsWorks decided this was a great update for some reason.

Any ideas how I can get my code running on 8 cores again?

Note: I was using R2010b (I think) and now using R2014b.

Comment: Did you try to set the number of workers using `parpool`?

Comment: See [How to set the max number of workers in parpool/matlabpool from console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639939/how-to-set-the-max-number-of-workers-in-parpool-matlabpool-from-console) maybe?

Comment: That works thank you. I was however hoping for a way of "fixing" `matlabpool` as it's more user friendly.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like @horchler has provided you with a direct [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639939/how-to-set-the-max-number-of-workers-in-parpool-matlabpool-from-console) to your question in the comments.

However, I would recommend sticking to the default 4 workers suggested by MATLAB, and not using 8. You're very unlikely to get significant speedup by moving to 8, and you're even likely to slow things down a bit.

You have four physical cores, and they can only do so much work. Hyperthreading enables the operating system to pretend that there are 8 cores, by interleaving operations done on pairs of virtual cores.

This is great for applications such as Outlook, which are not compute-intensive, but require lots of operations to appear simultaneous in order, for example, to keep a GUI responsive while checking for email over a network connection.

But for compute-intensive applications such as MATLAB, it will not give you any sort of real speed up, as the operations are just interleaved - you haven't increased the amount of work that the 4 real, physical cores can do. In addition, there's a small overhead in performing the hyperthreading.

In my experience, MATLAB will benefit slightly by turning hyperthreading *off*. (Of course other things, such as Outlook, won't: your choice).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, it's true that it doesn't always speed up the calculations and even slows some down depending on the calculations.